# FB.login() does not popup user login dialog?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
function shareFB(){console.log('reached share fb fn');
    $(".inviteshare .sendingmsg").show();
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {console.log('logged in');
            shareOnFacebook();
            console.log(response);
        } else {console.log('not logged in');
            FB.login(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    shareOnFacebook();
                    console.log(response);
                } else {
                    $(".inviteshare .sendingmsg").hide();
                    alert("User cancelled login or did not fully authorize");
                }
            },{scope:'publish_stream'});
        }
    },{scope:'publish_stream'});
}
```

i this is my code.it does not open login dialog .if i already logged in it works. that means it opens the shareonfacebook function.but if not logged in it does not woek (FB.login()) method. how do fix it?

Comment: There is no permission called publish_stream

Comment: Go read the documentation on FB.login - it says how to _Avoid Popup Blocking_ right at the top.